# Defining words using Java

Tags: java, word-list

I was wondering if there as an API in Java that can define words and find the origins of words. I remember awhile back searching this up and seeing "apache commons" but I am not sure.

So basically, the user will be able to enter a word "overflow" then the program will be able to define the word. So I am looking for an API that can define words and find origins of words. So the word "recherche" would have an origin that is "French".

Comment: Are you looking for the [lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemma_%28morphology%29) of tokens? Your question is a bit vague, you should clarify what you are after - preferably with an example.

Comment: I added the clarification. Hopefully, the question will be less vague.

Comment: Recherche is a german word too. You should be aware that the same word can exist in several languages.

Comment: Basically you would have to define a set of languages your word may come from and then somehow model the etymology of every word in those languages. A bit of optimization since words across multiple languages will share a 'history' and a layer on top that handles declination, misspellings and the such. Good luck implementing that. Try to look into natural language expert systems for ideas, maybe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/) will give you half of what you are looking for: you can look up the definition for a word.  Note that there are several implementations of WordNet for Java: [jwi](http://projects.csail.mit.edu/jwi/), [jaws](http://lyle.smu.edu/~tspell/jaws/index.html), [Dan Bikel's](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~dbikel/software.html#wn), [WordnetAPI](http://code.google.com/p/wordnetapi/).  Some of these might be easier to use for your purpose than *jwordnet* suggested by miku (I have only used *jaws* and *jwi*).

*Note*: WordNet will not give you origins (AFAIK).  I'm not aware of a software that does.

*Note*: You will have to provide the *lemma* of a word to be able to look it up in the dictionary.  This means that you will have to apply some Natural Language Processing (NLP) techniques if you want to do this automatically on a free-text document (which can contain inflected forms).  If you go this route, I'd suggest the [GATE](http://gate.ac.uk/) project's [Morph plugin](http://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch21.html#sec%3aparsers%3amorpher).

Answer (score 7):

Wordnet maybe? There is a Java wrapper for it: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jwordnet/

Another list of NLP toolkits:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_natural_language_processing_toolkits

To detect a language:

- http://www.jroller.com/melix/entry/nlp_in_java_a_language

Answer (score 4):

There is a website for etymology: http://www.etymonline.com/

It gives the result:
recherche 
1722, from Fr. recherché "carefully sought out," pp. of rechercher "to seek out." Commonly used 19c. of food, styles, etc., to denote obscure excellence.

Don't know if they got an API but use some sort of script to query it.

So find a good way of detecting "Fr." in the sentence above.

Cheers,
Erik

Answer (score 2):

Have you look for [JWKTL](http://www.ukp.tu-darmstadt.de/software/jwktl/)?

> "Wiktionary is a multilingual, web-based, freely available dictionary,
>   thesaurus and phrase book, designed as the lexical companion to
>   Wikipedia. Lately, it has been recognized as a promising lexical
>   semantic resource for natural language processing applications."

Using this, you can see the etymology of words.